# MVC 4 Configuration Error:"'MySql.Web, Version=6.7.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Today I installed Microsoft Web Matrix in my windows 8. After that I tried to run my already working MVC4 project  and I'm getting below Configuration error:

```
"Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Web, Version=6.7.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."
```

It also says it is located at,

```
Source File: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config    Line: 251
```

Things I tried:

1. I have uninstalled web matrix
2. I tried to remove version information from my machine.config. But is is not allowing to do so. it says "Access denied"
3. I tried to set WebMatrix reference in my visual studio to "Specific version=false"

what should i do? Your Answers would be really appreciated.

Comment: Do you use MySql.Web? If not, can you go to machine.config and remove the reference?

Comment: Hi Hiep, I tried to remove it. but I'm getting access denied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install [MySQL Connector](https://www.mysql.com/products/connector/) as your project seems to be using it and its unable to find it in your system or server.